# Registering an unpacked VSIX extension via MSI without using devenv /setup

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

We have a Visual Studio extension, currently installed with MSI, since we need to perform certain tasks after the installation (ngen, registering certain COM servers, etc). In the end of the installation, we run `devenv.exe /setup` (more specifically, `devenv.exe /setup /nosetupvstemplates` to make it a bit faster) to register the extension in Visual Studio 2012 and above (in 2010 this step was not required, since VS2010 would rebuild the extensions cache on every startup).

We're currently looking to move to a partial VSIX installation, but there are certain issues:

1. We have a certain folder structure (additional bundled tools). I wasn't able to find an option to include arbitrary folders and files with in VSIX package. Is this possible?
2. We're trying to avoid using `devenv.exe /setup`, since in rare cases, this may cause extensions not to load (as detailed by Remco Mulder on the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c483d83f-d640-4fe9-8ff7-af78d635df23/visual-studio-extension-caching-preventing-extensions-from-loading?forum=vsx)).
3. We still need to perform "post-installation" operations, currently not possible with VSIX.
4. Due to previous 'sins', we hardcoded some of the paths to use the `CompanyName\ProductName\Version` format that the VSIX packages *used to* follow, but it seems that VSIX randomy generate a folder name now (as Jason mentions in his answer below).

So what I'd essentially like is to be able to install an "unpacked" VSIX package - have the MSI installer create the file structure on disk (in the correct location, `%VSInstallDir%\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Company\Product\Version`), and then somehow to have VSIX consume the `.vsixmanifest` file to register the extension in Visual Studio.

(Initial digging into the Extension Manager API shows there's a method called `CreateInstalledExtension` in `ExtensionManagerService` that takes in a path to vsixmanifest, in assembly `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Implementation.dll`, but unfortunately it is internal).

So, without resorting to API hackery, is there any alternative way to essentially install an extension in Visual Studio (2012 and above), without using `devenv /setup`?

Comment: If you set `<InstalledByMSI>true</InstalledByMSI>` in the **source.extension.vsixmanifest**, and then unpack the files from the **.vsix** file to the **Extensions** folder, does it work if you omit the call to `devenv /setup`?

Comment: Yes, our vsixmanifest has InstalledByMSI set to true. Per Ed Dore's blog, in VS2012+, extensions are not being re-cached by default http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvst/archive/2012/10/08/your-vs-package-may-not-load-after-porting-it-to-vs-2012.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to launch the **VSIXInstaller.exe /quiet <vsix_path>** instead of unpacking the VSIX manually?

Comment: @280Z28 I'm currently looking into that. There's an issue with a randomly generated folder name, as Jason mentions in his answer below... it doesn't seem to be using the company/product name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Jason (and everyone else) suggests - yes, the "correct" (supported) way of registering a Visual Studio package externally is by running `devenv.exe /setup`, and for the most part - it works without problems (albeit slow, due to entire Visual Studio configuration being rebuilt).

This is a commercial product, and every once in a while we get a support case, complaining that after installing our extension, something bad happened in Visual Studio - other extensions failed to load, problem with Solution explorer, etc. Those cases are rare, but they do happen.

In an attempt to minimize the impact installing our extension does to the user's machine, I was trying to find a suitable way to use the VSIX installation mechanism that does not use `devenv.exe /setup`, but unfortunately, there isn't a supported scenario that handles all the issues I've raised in the question above.

After extensive research into the problem, I [found](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-install-a-visual-studio-extension-with-templates-via-an-msi/) an **undocumented, unsupported** solution that solves the problem completely! An empty file, called `extensions.configurationchanged`, located under `%VSInstallDir%\Common7\IDE\Extensions` gets [`touched`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_%28Unix%29) every time a VSIX package is installed or uninstalled, causing Visual Studio to refresh it's package cache (only!) on next restart! With modifying this file's "last modified date", it will essentially cause Visual Studio to act as if a VSIX package was just installed or uninstalled.

A few quick experiments of copying the extension files to an empty hive, and then touching the `extensions.configurationchanged` will cause Visual Studio to load the extension (and process all its .pkgdef files) on next restart - no `devenv /setup` necessary!

Several commercial products offer this solution in the Troubleshooting section of their online help, dealing with loading failure of their extension, so this solution might be the "lesser evil" I was looking for.

Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 6):

There is an undocumented command line switch that seems to have the same effect:
`devenv /updateconfiguration`

This switch simply changes the `ConfigurationChanged` value in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>`, forcing Visual Studio to reload all .pkgdef files and rebuild the `<version>_Config` key on the next startup.

It might be easier to do that modifying a file, from a MSI point of view.

Comment: Interesting! I did find this while searching, also I seen access to this key via Process Monitor, I assumed they do the same - each updating the other. In any event, the "touching" is very simple, just a matter of setting a last modified date on the file. In fact, it turns out Windows `copy` command supports this: `copy filename.ext +,,` does exactly that - "touch" the file without modifying it.

Comment: From my tests with Visual Studio 2015 RC, it seems that running `devenv.exe /setup` without elevation works, but erroneously gives you an error message telling you that it requires elevation.  (Perhaps it only partially works when not elevated.)  `devenv.exe /updateconfiguration` doesn't seem to have this problem - it works (or at least, it makes VS notice my new extension) without any error message.

Answer (score 4):

The supported way to do it is with `devenv /setup`. You should use `devenv /setup`. I agree that it's somewhat slow an annoying, but it should work fine.

For your #2 point above, I would not use a single instance of a single issue reported by a single customer to indicate that it "may cause extensions not to load". Looking at that forum thread, the problem was never root-caused and so the actual problem can't be inferred.

For #1, yes, you can include additional files in a .vsix. Selecting files within Solution Explorer will show a "Include in VSIX" item in the properties window for that file. The main limitation is you can't control *where* the extension is, as a whole, installed. So you can happily make folders of stuff, as long as you're OK that it's still put under a randomly-named folder to begin with.

Comment: Jason, thanks for the answers. With regards to point #2: it wasn't a single incident. we currently have statistics from 127 users who had experienced in some form or other, extensions failing to load after a 'devenv /setup'. I arrived at Remco's thread only after searching, and saw it described a similar issue.

Comment: Regarding package name, I never did understand the naming of the installed directory - could you please clarify on when does it get a random name vs CompanyName\Product\Version ?

Comment: It used to be name + version as your asking. Not sure why it was changed. To be honest, I like it since it forces people to not hard-code paths but rather do things correctly.

Comment: Jason, I completely agree with you with regards to not hardcoding the paths, which we unfortunately have. But this extension is quite old, and we're migrating it. "Best practices" will follow.

Answer (score 3):

Now that `Devenv /UpdateConfiguration` is [no longer an undocumented hack](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem/blob/master/doc/overview/mef.md), it should be the solution for everyone :)